# Call to Undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make() in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm just trying to implement a simple validation using Laravel Validator Facade. But it keeps giving me this error below:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make() in C:\xampp\htdocs..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 221

This is my code below:

```
use Validator;

/**
 * Validate the tenant's credentials
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return bool
 */
public function validate(array $data)
{
    $data = array_only($data, ['email', 'href']);

    $validator = Validator::make($data, $this->rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) return true;

    $this->errors = $validator->messages();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try adding a back slash to the Facade namespace `use \Validator`

Comment: I did. It still shows the same error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have searched using google before finally posting here. Any more idea on what I could do?

Comment: try: use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator`

Comment: i have tried that but still showing same error. Any more ideas on what to do please?

Comment: Would you be able to show your `rules` array as well?

Comment: `/**
     * @var array
     */
    private $rules = [
        'email'    => 'email',
        'href' => 'alpha_dash'
    ];`

Answer (score 3):

use this at the top of your script instead of the long namespaced Facade

```
use Validator;
```

and everything should be fine

Comment: Thiis is exactly what I have used. Kindly read my post again.

Comment: This saved my time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check if 'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider' is available or not in this file
app/config/app.php
If not then add this line 
`'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,`

Comment: Its available there and still showing the error. I really have no idea what is missing. Everything seems to be intact, yet, i still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you should try re-building the Laravel app by deleting the `vendor/` directory and running `composer install`.

Comment: This seems to work. But now my tests shows     `JobBoard\Tests\Application\Recruitment\TenantRegistrationTest::should_only_accept_valid_email_addresses
ReflectionException: Class validator does not exist`

Comment: I'd recommend testing your validator by pulling it out of the IOC. ie. Replace all your test Facade calls with `$this->app['validator']->make($data, $rules);`. Friendly reminder that facade's should be used as little as possible :)